# NX does not detect dependencies between apps and libs on remote servers

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I have an NX monorepo with a single app and multiple libraries.
When working with it on my device the dependency tree is created correctly, however when the same code is cloned on a remote machine, the dependencies are lost.
This causes issues during a build - for example, tailwind will not get info about libraries from which it has to extract classes.

I've compared NX versions, installed plugins, node versions - everything is the same.
When running the `nx graph --file graph.json` on my machine and on a remote server the dependency tree looks like this:

local:

```
"dependencies": {
  "utils-keyboard-shortcuts": [],
  "feature-internal-logs": [
    {
      "source": "feature-internal-logs",
      "target": "crud",
      "type": "static"
    },
    {
      "source": "feature-internal-logs",
      "target": "ui-hospitalization",
      "type": "static"
    },
    {
      "source": "feature-internal-logs",
      "target": "auth",
      "type": "static"
    },
    {
      "source": "feature-internal-logs",
      "target": "shared-gql-models",
      "type": "static"
    },
    {
      "source": "feature-internal-logs",
      "target": "shared-config",
      "type": "static"
    },[...]
```

remote:

```
"dependencies": {
  "utils-keyboard-shortcuts": [],
  "feature-internal-logs": [],
  "ui-hospitalization": [],
  "ui-loading-overlay": [], [...]
```

I've tried `nx repair` or `nx init` again but nothing seems to help.

Locally I am using macOS, the remote is ubuntu. I doubt it's a system thing because I can recreate the issue on other macOS machines.
There's something 'special' about my machine but I fail to determine what it is.

The workaround found by my colleagues was to downgrade to a previous version of nx.
We are using `14.8.2` and for them, after downgrading to `14.3.3` it seems to work fine.

Any info about where to look next will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `nx migrate` command needs to be run on all of the workspaces when upgrading `nx`. We thought doing so on a single device and then running `yarn install` on others is enough, but not.